# Layered Service Provider in vb6

Tags: vb6, winsock

can anyone help me with techniques on how 2 write Layered Service Provider in vb6. 
i am developing an application that will restrict site visited buy students in  school library.
please i need algorithms, maybe code or tutorial. am already well grounded in winsock.
am developing on windows os first, maybe later unix or linus etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A low-level system component such as an LSP would be quite difficult to write in a legacy langauge like VB6. Maybe you should consider switching to C++ or C#?

However, [Komodia seems to have a lot of information and examples](http://www.komodia.com/blog/index.php/tag/how-to-write-an-lsp/) about this subject.

Comment: thanks, but the sample i found is c++, an i don't even know how to compile it yet. can you help me 1) either a c++ to c# converter as am more convenient with c# or 2) tell me what i need and how o compile that source code, as there is no project file or 3) help me some more resource on the subject

Comment: The transition from C++ to C# should not be hard. If you start a new project in C# you should be able to convert the C++ example code - here's a very detailed article on the Microsoft MSDN on converting between the two languages: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301520.aspx